# Android Application crashes as getting image from URL to bitmap to ImageView

Tags: java, android, multithreading, url, bitmap

I know that this is a big beginner's problem and that it has to do with the correct number of threads and that you can't have too much going on in the UI thread, but I'm not exactly sure where this error is.

Here is my main (and only) activity's Java code :

```
   package com.example.bitmapdisplay;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    ImageView image;
    BitmapDrawable bd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(com.example.bitmapdisplay.R.layout.activity_main);

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(com.example.bitmapdisplay.R.id.ivImage);


    }

    protected void onStart() {
        ImageDownloader load = new ImageDownloader(image);
        load.execute("http://i1.cpcache.com/product_zoom/617914535/dickbutt_2_mug.jpg?side=Back&height=250&width=250&padToSquare=true");
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }



    public class ImageDownloader extends AsyncTask <String, Void, Bitmap> {

        ImageView image;
        public ImageDownloader(ImageView view) {

            image = view;
            view = null;
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {

            String url2 = url[0];

            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            byte[] imageData = getImagefromURL(url2);
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream), 250, 250, true);
            return bitmap;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }


    }

    public byte[] getImagefromURL(String url) {

        InputStream in = null;
        byte[] byteimage = null;

        try {
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection conn = imageUrl.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();

            int response = httpConn.getResponseCode();

            if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }

            int nRead;
            byte[] data = new byte[16384];
            ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            while((nRead = in.read(data,0,data.length)) != -1) {
                buffer.write(data,0,nRead);
            }

            buffer.flush();

            byteimage = buffer.toByteArray();

        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return byteimage;
    }

}
```

All of the XML should be in place. However, did I maybe mess up the threads? (I'm new to this).

Here is the logcat:

```
05-28 22:17:37.450: D/AndroidRuntime(844): Shutting down VM
05-28 22:17:37.450: W/dalvikvm(844): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1ab8ba8)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844): Process: com.example.bitmapdisplay, PID: 844
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bitmapdisplay/com.example.bitmapdisplay.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.example.bitmapdisplay.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:41)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
05-28 22:17:37.640: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: post the LogCat of your crash so we can see the Exception being thrown.

Comment: Is image null? Have you checked its finding the item?

Comment: Try removing image.setImageBitmap(bitmap) from your onStart() method as bitmap is null, which is what the logcat tells you.

Comment: ok, but when/where should I then set the bitmap on the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onCreate()` method,

Change:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(com.example.bitmapdisplay.R.id.ivImage);
```

to:

```
image = (ImageView) findViewById(com.example.bitmapdisplay.R.id.ivImage);
```

You have setup `ImageView image` as a instance variable but did not initialize it. You are getting a NullPointerException in your `onStart()` method because it is referencing the global variable `image` and in this case, it is null.

Comment: Yes I understand but the application still crashes when I try to run it. I'll edit my question's code to have your edits

Comment: Stick with me for a bit longer and i'll accept it ;)

Comment: @MJ93: "global variable" is not the right formulation here, since it belongs to the `Activity`. As far as I know there is no language construct in that could be described as "global variable" in java. Variables either belong to a instance (non-static), or to the class `static`. I suggest you choose a different wording.

Comment: I knew what he meant don't worry. But I think I might be doing something else wrong because I still get the NullPointException

Comment: @Stickerbomby: Could you please provide us with the new LogCat of the crash?

Comment: I figured it out. It had to do with too little threads being there and the UI couldn't handle it or something (plus a few minor bugs). Thanks to all who helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You did not initialize the `image` field in `onCreate`, but a local variable `image`.

You have a declaration and assignment in your `onCreate` method. You assign to the local variable `image`

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(com.example.bitmapdisplay.R.id.ivImage);
```

change that to

```
// no variable named image in this function -> assignment to field
image = (ImageView) findViewById(com.example.bitmapdisplay.R.id.ivImage);
```

If you don't do that, the `image` field of `ImageDownloader` is initialized to `null` in the constructor, since when it is called in `onStart` the `image` field of `MainActivity` still has it's default value (`null`). Therefore the `onPostExecute` of the `ImageDownloader` terminates appruptly with a `NullPointerException` or `image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` in `onStart` causes the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following code from method onStart:

```
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

load.execute actually started another asynchronous task to to load and build bitmap. When run this line, the bitmap will be absolutely null.

I can see the same code is correctly put in onPostExecute. It's enough.